# Regex match either or both, but not twice

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I'm struggling to think how I'd go about writing a regex that would match any of these:

```
pirates
scallywags
pirates scallywags
scallywags pirates
```

But not any of these:

```
pirates pirates
scallywags scallywags
pirates booty scallywags
booty pirates
```

Of course I could list out all of the possible permutations as alternates:

```
(pirates|scallywags|pirates scallywags|scallywags pirates)
```

But I feel like there should be an easier/more efficient way.

Comment: Re "*But I feel like there should be an easier/more efficient way.*", That is definitely the most efficient way

Comment: @ikegami according to regex101, the answer I accepted takes 31 steps to match `pirates scallywags` (30 if using the recursive method in the comments), vs 33 for the `(pirates|scallywags|pirates scallywags|scallywags pirates)`. While not a big difference, it's actually not more efficient.

Comment: In Perl, `'pirates scallywags' =~ /^(?:pirates|scallywags|pirates scallywags|scallywags pirates)\z/` takes 24 steps while `pirates scallywags' =~ /^(pirates|scallywags)(?! \1)( (pirates|scallywags))?\z/` takes 38 steps. The former is also [35-40% faster](https://pastebin.com/ydCrHNK3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not smart enough, but will work:

```
^(pirates|scallywags)(?! \1)( (pirates|scallywags))?$
```

Comment: A variant: `^(pirates|scallywags)(?: (?!\1)\g<1>)?$`.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I had a feeling it would involve negative lookaheads and backreferences but I couldn't quite piece it all together in my head. Thanks!

Comment: `$` (at end of string or at string-ending line feed) should be `\z` (at end of string). The second and third captures are performing the role of grouping, needlessly slowing things down. Use a grouping (`(?:...)`) instead of a capture (`(...)`).

Answer (score 3):

If you have only two words, then you already have the best solution (except for the needless capture and missing anchors).

If you have more words, then the regex engine isn't your best option.

---

The most efficient regex-based approach is the one you have:

```
$str =~ /^(?:pirates|scallywags|pirates scallywags|scallywags pirates)\z/
```

The downside is the code repetition. That can be avoided while preserving the most of the efficiency by building the pattern dynamically.

```
use Math::Combinatorics qw( );

sub build_re {
   my @quoted = map quotemeta, @words;
   my @alts;
   for my $r (1..$#words) {
      my $mc = Math::Combinatorics->new( count => $r, data => \@quoted );
      while ( my @combo = $mc->next_combination ) {
         push @alts, join " ", @combo;
      }
   }

   my $alt = join "|", @alts;
   return qr/^(?:$alt)\z/;
}

my @words = qw( pirates scallywags );
my $re = build_re(\@words, $re);

$str =~ $re
   or die "Invalid\n";
```

Ok, so it's not worth it for two words, but what if there are 5? Creating the 31 strings manually would be highly error-prone. The above code will create those 31 strings, and the Perl regex engine will create an efficient trie from them.

But is using the regex engine really the best option at that point? Let's work with a counted set instead.

```
sub check {
   my $words = shift;

   my %counts;
   ++$counts{$_} for split ' ', $_[0];

   my $any;
   for (@words) {
      my $count = delete($counts{$word})
         or next;

      return 0 if $count > 1;
      ++$any;
   }

   return $any && !%counts;
}

my @words = qw( pirates scallywags );
check(\@words, $str)
   or die "Invalid\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

[*When I wrote this, I imagined there could be other words before, after and in between the ones of interest. But that's not what you asked. I'll leave the answer here just in case someone finds it useful.*]

It's most readable to use multiple matches.

```
/\b(?:pirates|scallywags)\b/
&& !/\b booty \b/x &&
&& !/\b(pirates|scallywags)\b .* \b\1\b/xs
```

Using only two are already affects readability.

```
/\b(?:pirates|scallywags)\b/
&& !/ \b (?: booty | (pirates|scallywags)\b .* \b\1 ) \b/xs
```

It can be done using one.

```
/
   ^
   (?! .* \b (?: booty | (pirates|scallywags)\b .* \b\1 ) \b )
   .* \b(?:pirates|scallywags)\b
/xs
```

If you wanted to avoid scanning the string twice, you can use the following:

```
/
   ^
   (?:(?! \b(?:booty|pirates|scallywags)\b ).)*
   \b(?:pirates|scallywags)\b
   (?:(?! \b(?:booty|pirates|scallywags)\b ).)*
   \z
/xs
```

It turns out to be rather readable to those familiar with the `(?:(?!PATTERN).)*` idiom.

Which of these three is fastest may depend on the length of the strings being searched, how often they contain `pirates` or `scallywags`, how often they contain `booty`, and how close to their start `pirates` or `scallywags` is usually found when it is.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution but probably far from the best (negated match)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = qr/\b(pirates|scallywags)\b\s+\1|\bbooty\b/;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say if $_ !~ /$re/;
}


__DATA__
pirates
scallywags
pirates scallywags
scallywags pirates
pirates pirates
scallywags scallywags
pirates booty scallywags
booty pirates
```

Output

```
pirates
scallywags
pirates scallywags
scallywags pirates
```